# Passport login callback losing session

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js

I have the following code that stores the user referer HTTP header to the session so, after the facebook passport login had happened, I can know which page he was trying to access and redirect my user properly:

```
function facebookAction(req, res, next){
      var referer = req.headers['referer'];

      req.session.redirectLogin = url.format(parsed, true);

      passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: ['user_birthday', 'user_location', 'email']})(req, res, next);
}
```

The problem is that, after facebook calls back my URL, the session is not set anymore:

```
function facebookCallbackAction(req, res, next){
      var redirectLogin = req.session.redirectLogin;

      console.log(req.session.redirectLogin); // this is undefined

      passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: redirectLogin + 'login=1',
                                          failureRedirect: redirectLogin + 'loginError=1'})(req, res, next);
}
```

The login happens, but I lose the session for some reason.

Has anyone passed to this problem before?

I'm using sails as framework